# Format decimal 9999,99

Tags: .net, vb.net, formatting, decimal

Is there a format string to format a decimal to 000000000,00.
So first 9 digits, right padded with zeros if needed; a comma as fraction separator and two fraction digits.

- 0  => 00000000,00
- 12 => 00000012,00
- 987456,456 => 000987456,46

So something like myDecimal.ToString("D9") together with .ToString("F2")

Comment: Except for the extended method, do not think there's a method.

Comment: @Berat, what do you mean with the extended method?

Comment: Oh @Boris, I'm sorry. I did not know this aspect of `String.Format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decimal value = 0m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("000000000.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));
// 000000000,00

value = 12m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("000000000.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));
// 000000012,00

value = 987456.456m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("000000000.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));
// 000987456,46
```

Comment: passing a culture was the key. I wish there was a way to set decimal separator symbol without handing it a culture though.

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Format("{0:000000000.00}", mydouble);
```

you will get a , or . based on the current culture setting of the thread.

if you use:

[String.Format Method (IFormatProvider, String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx)

You can set the correct formatter

Comment: You will probably also get a thousands separator there, depending on culture settings too.

Comment: That's a custom numeric format string, you need to explicitly request the presence of thousands separator

Comment: This returns correct except that the decimal separator is a dot instead of a comma. Changing the format to use a comma ends up in something completely weird. This looks like a culture info thing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

```
Dim d1 = 0D
Dim d2 = 12D
Dim d3 = 987456.456
Dim d1formatted = String.Format("{0:000000000.00}", d1)
Dim d2formatted = String.Format("{0:000000000.00}", d2)
Dim d3formatted = String.Format("{0:000000000.00}", d3)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: This will use a dot instead of a comma for decimal separator